# UnsupportedClassVersionError despite using the correct Java version

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat, jdbc

I'm using JDBC SQL Server dependency in my project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
    <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>7.2.2.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

As you can see I'm using version 7.2.2.**jre8** and not 7.2.2.**jre11**.

I checked my java version with `java -version` and it says it's Java 1.8. I also checked `Eclipse > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs` and made sure I'm pointing to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_241. I also checked project's build path and Tomcat configuration and both point to this JDK. Maven's source and target tags are both set to 1.8.

Despite all of this, this exception is being thrown, which makes no sense to me, as I am using Java runtime 52 (Java 8) and the dependency I'm using is for java 8:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDriver has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ClassLoaderUtil.loadClass(ClassLoaderUtil.java:38)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connectUsingDriver(PooledConnection.java:281)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PooledConnection.connect(PooledConnection.java:212)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.createConnection(ConnectionPool.java:739)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:671)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:483)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:560)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:244)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:94)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:321)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:840)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.addResource(NamingContextListener.java:1015)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.createNamingContext(NamingContextListener.java:556)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.NamingContextListener.lifecycleEvent(NamingContextListener.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5007)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: The driver being is used is the one in the Tomcat lib folder, not the one in your WAR, so your Maven coordinates are irrelevant because that is not the driver that gets used. Replace the driver in your Tomcat installation with the right version.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Didn't know that Tomcat had its own lib folder...